# "Find Ally" hint in Uncharted 4 video game

Tags: capitalization

When you are far from your current ally and he or she has something to say to you a hint "Find Ally" appears. I wonder why this hint is written the way it is. I personally find it very weird and unusual.

Shouldn't it be for instance "Find your ally"? Why there is no "an" or "your" in the hint and why "Ally" starts with a capital letter? This makes it look like someone's name but there is no character named Ally in the game.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's very natural–in this context.

When you're playing a game and the game is giving you hints to read, it's important to keep them terse (short and simple) and readable. You can drop non-content words such as articles or pronouns (like *your*) in this context, and in others, such as in recipes, in instructions, on a grocery list, for example.

As for capitalization, it just looks better.

So in a computer game you might see hints such as (and most of these are ones I'm thinking up at random):

Find Ally
Get Help
Locate Food
Plant Mine
Drink Water
Bury Gold
Deposit Money
Give Cash
Buy Ammo
Search Body
Throw Grenade

short, pithy, and to the point.

You don't want something that takes long to read and can distract you from your game play, like

You've strayed away from your ally, we suggest you find him or her or find another one.

Comment: I guess there is a typo on "pithy".

Comment: You're welcome. I learnt good points, reading your answer. So I thank you:-)